# Simple soft synth with a random sounds generator advice.

Tags: random

Hello everyone,

I will be very thankful for any advice of yours concerning the following-

I look for the simplest synth software(with the not so many knobs) that can also generate random sounds (not only the waves, but for all of the other parameters as well), but all done via the use of the algorithm of the software only and without the use of any recordings or pre-made samples/patches.

The synth should provide the option to generate new random sounds as well as to be able to adjust them afterwards or to create sounds from zero.

I will also be happy for a software that is regularly updated, so I can keep working with in the future( I am looking for a payed software, so I could also have some support and ongoing maintenance)
I also look for an option to record the sessions of creating the sounds, if possible.
I do not have any MIDI, and look for a simple, standalone option for PC (windows)

Any idea is mostly and thankfully welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: C++ and maths. Possible duplicate: http://socialsounddesign.com/users/5631/i

Answer (score 1):

[MaxMSP](http://cycling74.com)?

It passes all criteria except for "simple."

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
But yes, I am looking for something simple and in a good price.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I love when a synthesizer has the "random" button.
You could try Atlantis (http://jeremyevers.com/atlantis/). I found it just wonderful.

Comment: At last!
This is exactly what I was looking for!
If you have any more ideas, just like this- I will be very thankful!
I am very thankful for your advice!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **free** alternative of Max/MSP (mentioned by Joel Corriveau) called Pd (Pure Data - http://puredata.info)

Answer (score 0):

Reaktor. If you know any DSP whatsoever you could make it in about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You may also enjoy [Metaphysical function](http://www.native-instruments.com/index.php?id=userlibrary&L=1&type=0&ulbr=1&plview=detail&patchid=9575).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!!!!

This is very helpful.

Comment: Please rank most helpful answer. If your question is answered mark it as solved. This will help others to find solution to similar problem. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

Cantabile can randomise any value in a VST and there's a free version.

http://www.cantabilesoftware.com/lite/

Try a bunch of random synths with it, I find it a very useful tool.

Absynth and Massive (like with Reaktor) also have random patch generators.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

It is a very good idea!